# Is is possible to render a normal template html.erb template with active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, activeadmin

I have a custom page in my admin built with active admin:

In **app/admin/stats.rb**:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Stats' do

  controller do

    def index
      @foo = 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

And in **app/views/admin/stats/index.html.erb**:

```
<h1> Admin stats</h1>
<p><%= @foo %></p>
```

When I go to /admin/stats, I see my page, but without the normal admin layout (like on the dashboard page)

How can I decorate my page with the default layout ?

---

I've tried:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Stats' do

  content do
    'foobar'
  end

  controller do

    def index
      @foo = 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

But this doesn't change anything. Still my stat page with no layout. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

In **app/admin/stats.rb**:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Stats' do

  content do
    render 'index'
  end

  controller do
    def index
      @foo = 'bar'
    end
  end

end
```

And rename `app/views/admin/stats/index.html.erb` to `app/views/admin/stats/_index.html.erb`  (Notice the `_`)

And it works fine.

From what I understand, if `index.html.erb` is present in `views/admin/stats`, the `content` block is not called. If `index.html.erb` is renamed into something else, then we go into the content block, then the layout rendering is called...